# как можно сделать точный поиск по каждой букву слева на право

Tags: javascript, jquery

как можно сделать точный поиск что при вводе например буквы "б" оно выдавало слово которые начинаються с первой буквы б, а не искало эту букву по всему слову как сейчас
js:

```
$("#searchCity").keyup(function() {
        var input, filter, container, elem, i, place, overlay;
        input = this;
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        container = document.getElementById("searchCityResult");
        elem = container.getElementsByClassName("city-options");
        document.querySelector(".search-city .custom-input").classList.add("cs-active");
        for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
            place = elem[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0];
            if (place.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                elem[i].style.display = "block";
            } else {
                elem[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените
`if (place.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)`
на 
`if (place.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter))`

Не забудьте прикрутить полифилл [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), если не используете транспайлеры.